# How to predict y values, once SVR model is made in a function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I wrote a function:

```
def SVR_model(X,y):
  gsc = GridSearchCV(
        estimator=SVR(kernel='rbf'),
        param_grid={
            'C': [0.1, 10, 1000],
            'epsilon': [0.0001, 0.01, 0.05,  5, 10],
            'gamma': [0.0001, 0.01, 1, 5, 10]
        },
        cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

  grid_result = gsc.fit(X, y)
  best_params = grid_result.best_params_  
  best_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=best_params["C"], epsilon=best_params["epsilon"], gamma=best_params["gamma"],
                   coef0=0.1, shrinking=True,
                   tol=0.001, cache_size=200, verbose=False, max_iter=-1)
  scoring = {
    'abs_error': 'neg_mean_absolute_error',
    'squared_error': 'neg_mean_squared_error'} 

  scores = cross_validate(best_svr, X, y, cv=10, scoring=scoring, return_train_score=True)
  return "MAE :", abs(scores['test_abs_error'].mean()), "| RMSE :", math.sqrt(abs(scores['test_squared_error'].mean()))


print(SVR_model(X_train,y_train))
```

Which outputs:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 1089 candidates, totalling 5445 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 1660 tasks      | elapsed:    2.3s
('MAE :', 0.0635194987170424, '| RMSE :', 0.0797596193815304)
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 5442 out of 5445 | elapsed:    7.7s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 5445 out of 5445 | elapsed:    7.7s finished
```

I've two questions about this:

1. I have a test set, and I want to use the model I trained on the test set, is that done like this?

   ```
    print(SVR_model(X_train,y_train))
    y_pred = SVR_model.predict(X_test)
    r2 = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
    print(r2)
   ```

When I run this code, I get:

```
----> 2 y_pred = SVR_model.predict(X_test)
      3 r2 = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
      4 print(r2)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

So I'm not just how to use the model I generate in the function, to predict values? Is it because I do not return the actual model as a function, but just an error score?

Can someone show me how to amend this function, so it returns the model that then I can run on X_test to predict y_test?

2. This is just a side question, how do I save this best model that was built in the function? Or to save y_pred? Is that possible?

(This is my first time attempting SVR with cross validation and grid search, all critique welcome. The data set is ~150 columns of floats, and the label/target is also a float, so this is a regression problem).

Comment: Predict is a method of the classifier. So your function should return a classifier to be able to use it. The gsc.best_estimator_ should return the best estimator your are looking for. Your function could return it, so you can use predict directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your SVR_model(X,y) function should return a classifier objet. You can return the best one found with the GridSearchCV function.

```
def SVR_model(X,y):
   ...
   gsc = GridSearchCV(...)
   gsc.fit(X, y)
   return gsc.best_estimator_
```

so you can use the function in your code to get the best estimator and call the predict method with it.

```
model = SVR_model(X_train,y_train)
print("model optimized and trained")
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
r2 = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(r2)
```